# Does the Unit Test Framework compiles code need to be unit tested

Tags: c++, unit-testing, junit

I want to understand if in general any standard Unit Test Framework for C/C++/Java compiles the code that need to be unit tested?

My understanding is that it does not compile it but it just execute the test cases. We have to compile the code to resolve the compilation issues. Unit test framework does not report compilation or linker errors.

And in case if it compiles we will need to configure compiler with Unit Test Framework.

Comment: It will depend how you set stuff up. If you add a source files into the tests and a dependency, rather than using a lib, it might compile it - if required. How do you have things setup?

Comment: Tool chain usually resolves dependencies. When you build unit test well configure project will first build production code, then unit test and run tests. Test is just application or dll loaded by tool, so tool chain just resolves defined dependencies when you try to run it. Test framework has nothing to build process.